# Use HAProxy or Nginx to Load Balance between VPS

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, vps, haproxy

I want to load balance + failover backup multiple vps webservers hosted on different providers.

I heard that for HAProxy you need multiple server under the same subnet, plus a shared (virtual) ip address between load balancers.

But it's not possible in my case cause every VPS is on different node/network.

1. Is there a way to use HAProxy in this kind of setup ? ( **Please explain how briefly, I don't want to hear your "YES" answer** )
2. What about NginX? Is it possible to achieve same result with Nginx ? (when servers are located on different nets)

I know about Round Rubin DNS, but it doesn't provide a real failover solution, neither a load balance between servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load balance and High Availability(HA) are two different things.
Yes, you can configure load balance, using NginX, for two or more nodes, regardless where are they located.

**For Load Balance you have:**
DNS -> service IP -> Load balancer -> AppSrv1,AppSrv2,...,AppSrvn -> One or more Backends

**For High Availability(HA) you have:**

- Active/Passive:
  Normal work situation:
  DNS -> Virtual Service IP (assigned on LB1) -> AppSrv1,AppSrv2,...,AppSrvn -> One or more Backends
  If LoadBalancer1 (LB1) breaks:
  Hartbeat assigns VirtualIP to LB2
  DNS -> Virtual Service IP (assigned on LB2) -> AppSrv1,AppSrv2,...,AppSrvn -> One or more Backends
- Active/Active:
  DNS -> VirtIP1 (LB1),VirtIP2 (LB2), VirtIPn (LBn) -> AppSrv1,AppSrv2,...,AppSrvn -> One or more Backends

Basically, Load Balancer creates hashes, based on client IP, and forwards all traffic with this hash to the same AppSrv (in order to preserve sessions, etc). You can configure preferred AppSrv, failover AppSrv, etc

You can make a configuration with LB on all of your VPSs, which forwards traffic to the local AppSrv(same VPS), and if that AppSrv is unreachable, then forward to the "backup" VPS. But there are problems with such implementation on so many levels...

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is, Redirect user's download request to a server that is available(not down) and free on resource compared to other servers (in term of CPU usage, RAM, Traffic, Number of alive connection ). Is this same as Load Balance or HA ? What should I look for actually.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is Load Balance. It's easy to do it for "server that is available(not down)".  
I'm not sure if NgineX can collect server metrics and make a decision upon them. You probably have to look for external solution.

Comment: Thank you for clearing up my thoughts. I looked for load balance using nginx and It was super EASY to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You have confused HSRP/VRRP/LVS with HAProxy. The virtual IP part is completely separate to HAProxy.

If you want a single shared IP between two different VPS providers, you can't. The best you can do is get two VPS's from the same provider, run heartbeat+haproxy on both, then they can have IPs within the same subnet.

Comment: You mean there is no way to Load Balance 2 or more servers over a global network ? They have to be on same network ? This doesn't make sense. There should be a way to use a server to load balance different located servers.

Comment: It makes sense - you just don't understand. With MPLS or BGP - yes. With a bunch of VPS's from different providers - no. You would never be able to "float" a virtual IP between different providers.  The best you could get is DNS to balance between those, then each of those balance between the backends - but then you're reliant on DNS - which isn't remotely appropriate for load balancing.

Comment: sonnasi, you're mistaking HA with load balance. LB starts with LB proxy server, which distributes client's request between active/active servers. This means, those servers can be anywhere in the net, as long as they're accessible from the LB proxy. Performance and efficiency are another matter.

Comment: I'm not mistaking either. The OP was looking for a way to use multiple VPS's to load balance

Comment: I'm not mistaking either. The OP was looking for a way to use multiple VPS's to load balance amongst multiple back ends. But was mentioning the use of a virtual IP, which means they were looking at UltraMonkey/Heartbeat or otherwise, in conjunction with HAProxy. The OP asked for load balancing plus failover - something you wouldn't get with a single load balancer, nor would you get with "DNS load balancing". You can't be highly available using a single load balancer, nor using DNS to load balance.

Comment: And you cannot float a single IP between different providers without the use of either an MPLS network or BGP announcement. Either of which are far out of reach of the OP's capability and understanding. DNS is neither suitable for load balancing nor High Availability and your answer is just plain inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

You mean different farms located in different areas?

Then you would route them through DNS to the specific geographic farm where
HAProxy can load balance:

webfarm1 -> HAProxy -> appsrv..

webfarm2 -> HAProxy -> appsrv..

You can also load balance between vps spread across geographical areas but the
end result would not be that good: this kind of setup servers usually static content
such as CDN's.